# How to use jsjspy run the python file inside html

Tags: javascript, python, html, file, pypy

How to run python file in html?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    pypyjs.ready()
    .then(function() {
         pypyjs.execfile("C:/Users/User/Desktop/FYP/Prototype/FYP front end/FYP front end/new.py")
     });

</script>
```

I just want to run the file no need any output over there

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean pypy.js https://github.com/pypyjs/pypyjs ? As it states in the README, "development is sleeping, use pyiodide instead"

Comment: I just want a button that to run python file in html.